# How do I set up an ASP.NET build server?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I want to create an ASP.NET build server for the first time since I've never used it.

Does anyone have a tutorial or resource on how to make an ASP.NET build server?

Or can anyone tell me how it's done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If by "create" you mean "setup a build server" then I suggest you take a look at [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/index.html) from JetBrains.

TeamCity is a multi purpose build server and can be used to build ASP.NET projects as well. You can get up and running for free, and its very easy to set up, compared to CruiseControl.Net.

Take a look at [MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2019) to see how to do specific ASP.NET build stuff.

- [MSBuild reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reference?view=vs-2019)
- [How to use MSBuild to do ASP.NET compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/videos/aspnet-35/how-do-i/how-do-i-use-msbuild-to-automate-the-aspnet-compiler-and-merge-utilities) (video)
- You might need something from the [msbuildtasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks) open source task collection

If you really want to create your own build server from scratch (but why?), I can't help you.

Answer (score 6):

You could make a build server using [CruiseControl.NET](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) which can build your project.

- [CruiseControl.Net Tutorial – Part 1](https://ilmatte.wordpress.com/2008/06/01/cruisecontrolnet-tutorial-part-1/)
- [CruiseControl.Net Tutorial – Part 2](https://ilmatte.wordpress.com/2008/06/15/cruisecontrolnet-tutorial-part-2/)

There is no ASP.NET build server as such.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a one-click build script? If not, you should create that first. Once you are able to run a single command and get a complete build, then it is easy to set up CruiseControl or some other build server.

Comment: Every .Net project file is a build script if you call it from the command line: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Given the strength of the build servers out there it's *really* not sensible to spend any time developing your own.

You will, however, need at the minimum

- a one-click build script
- a source code repository (e.g. Subversion, TFS, or even [shudder] SourceSafe)
- a server to use as a build box (I use a virtual image)

You may also find a one-click deployment script written using something like Powershell to be useful, too.

Note that a very effective alternative to CruiseControl.NET and TeamCity is [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/). Although it's written in Java it's ridiculously simple to get going with a J2EE server like Tomcat.

The key strength of Hudson is the range the plug-ins, which allow you to monitor most version control systems and then not just build (through MSBuild or even the command line) but also run unit tests, acceptance tests, and so on.

Comment: Beware, I'd almost downvote just for mentioning sourcesafe ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You might look at Web Deployment Projects -- they allow you to build your site and merge all DLLs into a single file, for a fully pre-compiled site.  You can use it with MSBuild.

An option on the automation side is Team Foundation Server's (TFS) automated builds.  TFS also includes source control, bug tracking and many other features you may or may not need.